# How do I animate the month changes in a jquery ui date picker when i click next/prev buttons

Tags: jquery-ui, animation, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like a datepicker like the one found here:

[datepicker example](https://www.tripadvisor.ie/Hotels)

I am using the jquery ui datepicker with much success. I am showing 2 months at a time just like the one in the link but I would like it to animate with a slide when I click the next/prev month buttons.

I have tried this but it animates the entire datepicker, i.e. the entire datepicker slides out then back in again.

```
onChangeMonthYear: (year, month, inst): void => {
    $('.ui-datepicker')
                    .hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300)
                    .show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 300);
}
```

here is a fiddle:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjawymxc/)

SOLVED thanks to AB Udhay. I removed the onChangeMonthYear function and put this in the contructor(using TypeScript):

```
        $(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', () => {
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar')
                .hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 200)
                .show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 200);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-prev', () => {
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar')
                .hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 200)
                .show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 200);
        });
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle just only with the datepicker?

Comment: added. thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"onChangeMonthYear" method will trigger after the date and month has changed. So you do something like this on click of the buttons.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjawymxc/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', function () {
  $(".ui-datepicker-title>span").hide().show(300);
  $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300).show('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 300)
})

$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-prev', function () {
  $(".ui-datepicker-title>span").hide().show(300);
  $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 300).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 300)
})
```